# Google Chrome: The vertical scroll bar sometimes disappears on some web pages

Tags: css

Google Chrome: The vertical scroll bar sometimes disappears on some web pages

This problem does not always occur. Usually at once every 5 times
Most often, when I go from the google search engine to the website, the sidebar then disappears

https://kaldekor.pl/3670289-zarowka-led-do-girland-1w-zimna-biala-przezroczysty

https://www.google.com/search?q=%C5%BBar%C3%B3wka+Led+Do+Girland+1w+kaldekor&sxsrf=AOaemvIsDADCy7dVWA2A166C_kMgFNIGsw%3A1643025898911&ei=6pXuYYb-Nu-MrgT4jaioAg&ved=0ahUKEwiGm764rMr1AhVvhosKHfgGCiUQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%C5%BBar%C3%B3wka+Led+Do+Garland+1w+kaldekor&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABOgoIIxCuAhCwAxAnSgQIQRgBSgQIRhgAUO0GWIIMYSAMMNaAAGHYAHgBAgAFYQlcgBwAGWIAQMgBwAGWIAQMgBwAGWIAQMgBwAGWIAQMgBAg

Comment: what OS ur checking on?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I started experiencing an intermittently disappearing vertical scrollbar in Chrome not only on my own website, but also on others' websites, somewhere in the last month or so.  The vertical scrollbar disappeared intermittently when I used Chrome's back and forward buttons.

The intermittently disappearing vertical scrollbar on use of back-foward buttons was not due to an overlay flag, installed extensions, or hardware acceleration (all tested, with no success in solving the problem).

It turns out that the intermittently disappearing vertical scrollbar was not specific to my own website, and was happening on other websites, too (suggesting to me this was a Chrome issue and not a website issue).

It also turns out that the intermittently disappearing vertical scrollbar on use of the back-forward buttons ONLY happened on Chrome, not Firefox, Edge, Opera or IOS.

Cleaning and resetting Chrome did no good. Javascript to control or style the Chrome scroll bar, and css to require the scrollbar at all times, had no effect.

I noticed that when using Chrome's incognito mode, the vertical scrollbar never disappeared with use of the back-forward buttons.

I tested the back-forward cache in dev tools (Application, Cache, Back/forward cache, Test back/forward cache), and could see that the vertical scrollbar was not being inserted by the cache.

I then went to chrome://flags and disabled the "back-forward cache" and the vertical scrollbars no longer intermittently and randomly disappear when using the back and forward buttons, and I have control of the scrollbars with javascript and css.

Comment: Thanks! This flag fixes it. To a chrome dev who happen to investigate this issue: A site with vertical scrollbar disappearing on back-forward is your beloved [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that this issue happens because of activating some extensions.
In order to solve this problem you should first capture which extension cause the issue so please do the following:

1- Disable all the the extensions from your Chrome browser.

2- Update your browser to the last version.

3- Close the browser and reopen it.

4- Try to navigate web pages and run the extensions individually (meaning: run one extension and then carry on browsing, if the problem doesn't happen turn on the second one an so).

5- if the problem happens again after turning on one extensions then try to delete it and replace it with appropriate one.

Comment: This is not a browser problem. I checked on different computers. There is a problem with the css on the site. However, I don't know exactly what could be causing this situation.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be ad-blocker. I disabled it using the 3dots when on the problem page, all good now.